# Angular2 build getlocation from googlemaps Service

Tags: google-maps, angular, service, components

I want to create a service where i can get my current location.
I want to put this in a service so that i can use this location in several Components.

The issue is that when i try this my component tries te get the lat and lon before google maps finishes the ajax call.

Does somebody has a solution for this issue?

```
setCurrentPosition() {

        if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            this.zoom = 12;

            return this.latitude, this.longitude ;
          });
        }
      }
```

This is how i get my location in the service.
My components want to use the latitude and longitude to soon because the ajax call hasn`t jet retrieved the informatio. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used promises before you can even use a promise for this. The promise will resolve when the api gets lat and lng. You can call api like

```
this.setCurrentPosition().then((response)=>{
  this.lat = response.latitude;
 this.lng = response.longitude;
}); 

         setCurrentPosition() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                    let res = {
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude:position.coords.latitude
                    }
                    resolve(res);
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Have added a new ans . You can check.

Comment: Dont really understand your solution and it gives errors. I used promises in Angular1 since when do we also use them in angular2?

Comment: We have promises in angular2 also http://learnangular2.com/es6/promises

Comment: now it gives error on }); it says expected , @remyaJ

Comment: I am also using Typescript is this an issue? @RemyaJ

Comment: No that is not an issue. Check if brackets are correct.

Comment: I looked at it can`t find the issue

Comment: there was a problem with my closing braces.now I have edited my ans.

Comment: I did not add () for function.Now everything is working fine.Can you accept and upvote my ans if it worked for you.

Comment: No did not work for me @remyaj when i try to pull the properties lat long in my component is says that the property does not exist!

Comment: why are you not getting I tried and I got.Can you share your fiddle.I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Write your function as an observable amd subscribe to it from your component so it will get value once the latitude and longitude are returned by this service . Refer https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html

Comment: never used observables before so i will search for is can you help me with example from my issue?